# How can I programmatically create a node?

Tags: 8, nodes

How can I programmatically create nodes with date and image fields?

I know I can do it in Drupal 7 with the following code.

```php
global $user;
    
$node = new stdClass();
$node->title = "YOUR TITLE";
$node->type = "YOUR_NODE_TYPE";
node_object_prepare($node);
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$node->uid = $user->uid; 
$node->status = 1; //(1 or 0): published or not
$node->promote = 0; //(1 or 0): promoted to front page

$existing_filepath = "/home/nzcodarnoc/sites/default/files/imported/picture.jpg";
$new_filepath = "public://picture.jpg";
$drupal_file = file_save_data(file_get_contents($existing_filepath), $new_filepath);
$drupal_file->alt = $node->title;
$drupal_file->title = $node->title;
$node->field_my_file[$node->language][0] = get_object_vars($drupal_file);
$node->birth_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = time();  
$node = node_submit($node);
node_save($node);
```

What is the equivalent code for Drupal 8?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The following code will help you to save an image in a new node.

```php
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use \Drupal\file\Entity\File;
 
// Create file object from remote URL.
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.drupal.org/files/druplicon.small_.png');
$file = file_save_data($data, 'public://druplicon.png', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
 
// Create node object with attached file.
$node = Node::create([
  'type'        => 'article',
  'title'       => 'Druplicon test',
  'field_image' => [
    'target_id' => $file->id(),
    'alt' => 'Hello world',
    'title' => 'Goodbye world'
  ],
]);
$node->save();
```

Comment: The reality loop link no longer leads to the Drupal 8 info page.

Answer (score 17):

I think that object oriented way is more convenient, isn't it?

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$my_article = Node::create(['type' => 'article']);
$my_article->set('title', 'My article');
$my_article->set('field_text', 'My text');
$my_article->set('field_image', FID);
$my_article->set('field_user', UID);
$my_article->enforceIsNew();
$my_article->save();
```

Answer (score 16):

In drupal 8 entities are objects and as such, to create an entity is to create an instance of the entity's type class.
If you know the class of the entity then you can either use the new keyword or the create function.

I.E. `$foo = new Foo();` or `$foo = Foo::create();`

If you don't know the class of entity (only the machine name) then you can use the request the Storage class like so: `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type_id)->create();`

To populate the fields of an entity you can either use the `$entity->set($key, $value)` method on the entity object or pass a `key=>value` array to the entity constructor. As such:

```
$foo = new Foo([
  'name'=>'bar',
  'baz'=> TRUE,
  'multi_value' => [
    'first',
    'second',
    'third',
  ]
]);
```

To save an entity you only have to call the `$entity->save()` method on the entity object.

Since files in drupal 8 are also entities you need to either pass the id of the file entity, or the actual file entity, as the value.

```
$file_1 = File::load(1);
$foo->set('bar_files', [
  $file_1,
  2
]);
```

Here is a code for your specific scenario:

```
$node_entity_type = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinition('node');
// The [file_save_upload][1] function returns an array of all the files that were saved.
$poster_images = file_save_upload($upload_name, $validators, $destination);
$node = new Node([
  $node_entity_type->getKey('bundle') => 'movie',
  $node_entity_type->getKey('label') => 'Foo',
  'field_release_date' => '1/1/2015',
  'field_poster_image' => $poster_images,
]);
$node->save();
```

Comment: I want to add one image field and one date ffield,provide your answer with this field types.

Comment: But how to populate text fields programmatically in Drupal 8, at the time of node creation?

Comment: The data in $node_data is mapped directly to the node fields. If you want to add text to a field called field_body just add another entry with the key field_body.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more details. You are welcome.

Comment: "I.E. $foo = new Foo(); or $foo = new Foo();" How was this supposed to read?

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do it in the most clean way (testable), use `entity_type.manager` service:

```
$storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage($entity_type_id);
$my_entity = $storage->create([
   ....
]);
```

The problem with `Node::create` function, that it is static call, and that's why you cannot really unit test your class anymore. Avoid doing static calls whenever it's possible. It will make your code more readable (because dependencies will be clear).

Answer (score 6):

Following code is working for me

```
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use \Drupal\file\Entity\File;

$node = entity_create('node', array(
'type' => 'article',
'title' => $form_state->getValue('title'),
'body' => array(
'value' => $form_state->getValue('body'),
'format' => 'basic_html',
),
'uid' => $uid,
));
$node->save();
```

Comment: entity_create is deprecated

Comment: Also, `$form_state` is available only in specific contexts; otherwise, you cannot access it.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to create node with image is:

```
use \Drupal\file\Entity\File;

// Create file object from remote URL.
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.drupal.org/files/druplicon.small_.png');
$file = file_save_data($data, 'public://druplicon.png', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->create(array(
  'type'        => 'article',
  'title'       => 'Druplicon test',
  'field_image' => [
    'target_id' => $file->id(),
    'alt' => 'Hello world',
    'title' => 'Goodbye world'
  ],
));
$node->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use Drupal\Core\Language\Language;


$definition = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinition('node');
$values = [
    $definition->getKey('bundle') => 'basic_page',
    'langcode'                    => Language::LANGCODE_NOT_SPECIFIED,
    'title'                       => '...',
];
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->create($values);
```