# How to create custom ECK entity class (per bundle)

Tags: 8, entities

With ECK I created Entity type Vehicle, and added 2 bundles, Car and Truck

Goal is to have a class `Car` so I can use `Car::create()` and similar entity functions, and also implement my own functions.

As far as I came is creating `Vehicle` class, and it's working, but I'm struggling with bundles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is impossible to do what you want. A bundle is not a sub-class of an entity as you seem to be assuming.

Classes are always defined in code and are always provided by a module. ECK uses a workaround but in fact only defines one entity type: [`EckEntity`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/eck/tree/src/Entity/EckEntity.php?h=8.x-1.x), it then performs some tricks to let Drupal see this as different entity types.

Creating entities for every bundle dynamically (since a user can add / remove bundles) would be difficult and appears to be only possible using dirty tricks like this:

```
// With a property
$myclassname = "anewclassname";
$myproperty = "newproperty";
eval("class {$myclassname} { protected \${$myproperty}; }";
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15579465/1293725

I am pretty sure Drupal does not support this (luckily).

Bundles are stored as properties on the entity, often (always?) as the `type` property, have a look at this example:

```
// Create node object with attached file.
$node = Node::create([
  'type'        => 'article', // < - this is the bundle
  'title'       => 'Druplicon test',
  'field_image' => [
    'target_id' => $file->id(),
    'alt' => 'Hello world',
    'title' => 'Goodbye world'
  ],
]);
$node->save();
```

From: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/189095/9921

So in your case, you would need to do this:

```
$car = Vehicle::create([
  'type'        => 'car',
   ...
]);
```

Or define a new class for your bundles, but you would need to either use the eval method above to create a class for all your bundles, or define them in code and loose flexibility. Then in that class extend the Vehicle class and in the constructor provide the `type` or something. For the sake of readability of your code I guess it would be best to just follow conventions and not create classes for bundles.