# Kernel Test: Programmatically create a vocabulary and add a field to it

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, testing

I want to add a taxonomy term and add field to it. My current code looks this way:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\Tests\permissions_by_term\Kernel;

use Drupal\KernelTests\KernelTestBase;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Vocabulary;

/**
 * Tests the ERR composite relationship upgrade path.
 *
 * @group permissions_by_term
 */
class SelectTermTest extends KernelTestBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static $modules = array('taxonomy', 'text');

  /**
   * List of taxonomy term names by language.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  public $termNames = [];

  /**
   * The vocabulary used for creating terms.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\taxonomy\VocabularyInterface
   */
  protected $vocabulary;

  function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    $this->installEntitySchema('taxonomy_term');

    // Create a vocabulary.
    $this->vocabulary = Vocabulary::create([
      'name' => 'Views testing tags',
      'vid' => 'views_testing_tags',
    ]);
    $this->vocabulary->save();

    // Add a translatable field to the vocabulary.
    $field = FieldStorageConfig::create(array(
      'field_name' => 'field_foo',
      'entity_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
      'type' => 'text',
    ));
    $field->save();
    FieldConfig::create([
      'field_name' => 'field_foo',
      'entity_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
      'label' => 'Foo',
      'bundle' => 'views_testing_tags',
    ])->save();
  }

  public function testSomething() {
  }

}
```

If I run the test by the following command:

> vendor/bin/phpunit -c modules/permissions_by_term
>   modules/permissions_by_term/tests/src/Kernel/SelectTermTest.php

I'm getting the following output:

> PHPUnit 4.8.11 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> E
>
> Time: 882 ms, Memory: 6.00Mb
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1)
>   Drupal\Tests\permissions_by_term\Kernel\SelectTermTest::testSomething
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\Exception\NoCorrespondingEntityClassException: The
>   Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig class does not correspond to an
>   entity type.
>
> /home/peter/Websites/pbt-d8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeRepository.php:98
>   /home/peter/Websites/pbt-d8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityManager.php:375
>   /home/peter/Websites/pbt-d8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Entity.php:509
>   /home/peter/Websites/pbt-d8/modules/permissions_by_term/tests/src/Kernel/SelectTermTest.php:49
>
> FAILURES! Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Errors: 1.

I do not understand this part:

> Drupal\Core\Entity\Exception\NoCorrespondingEntityClassException: The
>   Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig class does not correspond to an
>   entity type.

As an example I have used the Drupal core taxonomy test from

> core/modules/taxonomy/src/Tests/Views/TaxonomyFieldFilterTest.php

This test does what I want to do, but is not a Kernel test. It is a Simpletest, since it inherits from WebTestBase. If I use WebTestBase, it works. But the test is much slower then. Do you know what's missing in my code for running it as a Kernel Test?

Comment: I didn't try but I guess it should be similar as creating node with field. Please take a look on the answer of this [post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/189095/56904).

Comment: This is corrected.

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far. Actually I want to create an automated test for taxonomy terms. For my test I need to add a field to a taxonomy term. I tried it the following way so far: [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/jepster/363f8ce3b43d9ca6490eb1d39b29c42e)

But I get the following error:

Drupal\Core\Entity\Exception\NoCorrespondingEntityClassException: The Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig class does not correspond to an entity type.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The way you show us is to create a vocabulary and attach a field to that vocabulary. You question is misleading, could you update it?

Comment: You have been right, what I really wanted to do was to create a vocabulary and add a field to it. I was thinking I need to add a field to the term. Thanks for the hint. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 7):

You need to enable the field module so its entity types are present. Kernel test base *does not* enable required modules so the FieldConfig and FieldStorageConfig entity types don't exist until you enable the field module. Put it in the $modules property with 'taxonomy' and 'text'.

Answer (score 5):

You should try FieldKernelTestBase instead of just KernelTestBase. There is a helper method called createFieldWithStorage who will do the job.

Comment: Why not just export and import the config? Instead of recreating the fields with storage? Just curious