# How can I programmatically insert content via a script or import instead of through the UI?

Tags: 8, database, plugins

I have a custom content type and I now need to create thousands of entries using that type. It would take a very, very long time to go through the interface and add these one by one. I'm hoping there is a plugin, module, or some kind of API so that I can create all of these entries in an excel and simply import them into the database. Is this possible?

I have not been able to get Drush working so that isn't really an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct answer to your question is [Migrate Source XSL module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_source_xls) for the D8 Migrate API.

Or hell, dont have Windows/Excel installed do the same with [Google Sheets Migrate Plus plugin](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_google_sheets).

I'm not sure if there is a UI for Migrate yet in D8. But this would be the most flexible solution. If needed you could use the drupal api itself to code simple insertion from a php script to create Nodes from an excel script; but the above migrate plugins should be much for flexible to debug in the long run -- but may require Drush support currently.

### Edit

Ask previously, how to create a Node in D8:
[Programmatically create nodes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185442/programmatically-create-nodes)

Comment: But the fields for each content type are all in separate tables in the database. If I use the drupal API to code an insertion, do I have to manually update every field in every table or is there an API that can hook into my custom content type? The Entity API?

Comment: Hey one more question about the stackoverflow link you referenced above. Where would I place and run that script?

Comment: Nevermind. I made a module and I just load that page and I am able to insert new content. This worked great!