# Cloning nodes between multisite instances with separate databases

Tags: 8, nodes

I'm working on a Drupal 8.6 multisite and my client wants to be able to duplicate content between many of these sites. The codebase of the websites is the same, but each of them uses a different database. For that, I made a module with some hooks that gets the node serialized and posts it to another site. code below:

```
function a8_replicate_node_insert(Node $node) {
  $type = $node->getType();

  if($type == 'event')
  {
    $portals = $node->get('field_duplicate_to_portal')->getValue();
    $serializer = \Drupal::service('serializer');
    $data = $serializer->serialize($node, 'json', ['plugin_id' => 'entity']);
    $data = json_decode($data); // make it array again

    foreach ($portals as $url) {
      try{
        a8_replicate_post_to_other_site($url['value'], $data, 'insert');
      }
      catch (\Exception $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
      }
    }

  }
}
```

The `a8_replicate_post_to_other_site` function just uses `curl` to post the data as json to the other website. Then I made another module to receive the content, with the following function:

```
  public function receive() {
    $ip = \Drupal::request()->getClientIp();
    // to make sure it's the machine posting to itself
    if($ip == '127.0.0.1') {
      $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

      if($data['action']=='insert') {

        $node = Node::create($data['node']);
        $node->save();// <<<< error happens here 
      }
    }
  }
```

It's my first Drupal development and I'm I don't know pretty well what I'm doing.

Is this the right way to create a node? Is there a better and safer way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically create nodes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185442/programmatically-create-nodes)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the approach you used. Here is my recommendation.

First, define your database connection to each multisite on the default setting.php with different name, check the example below:

```
#Default site 

$databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'dbname',
  'username' => 'uname',
  'password' => 'password',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'host',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);

#Site 1
$databases['site1']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'dbname',
  'username' => 'uname',
  'password' => 'password',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'host',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);

#Site 2
$databases['site2']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'dbname',
  'username' => 'uname',
  'password' => 'password',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'host',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

Now, on hook_node_insert you can save the node object to multiple databases by changing the database each time, refer the code below as an example:

```
// Switch to site 1 database 
\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection('site1');
//$node will have all fields you need 
$site1Node = Node::create([
    'type'        => $node->getType();,
    'title'       => $node->getTitle();,
    'body_text'   => $node->get('body')->value,
]);
$site1Node->save();
// Switch to site 2 database 
\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection('site2');

$site2Node = Node::create([
    'type'        => $node->getType();,
    'title'       => $node->getTitle();,
    'body_text'   => $node->get('body')->value,
]);
$site2Node->save();

// finnally make sure to swich back to default datyabase 
\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection();
```

Comment: I like your approach. What about all the other properties and relationships?

Comment: Should I use a 'use' sentence for the database switch to work? I'm doing it but it's not switching the database

Comment: The database switching class is using the full namespace to call the function, Probably you will need to add Node namespace `` use Drupal\node\Entity\Node; ``
Also, please feel free to share your code too.

Answer (score 0):

this module does it all! it's awesome!

https://www.drupal.org/project/single_content_sync

Answer (score -1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Have you had a look at either of these modules that are both feature rich and accomplish the objective?

https://www.drupal.org/project/content_sync

https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_pilot

Comment: Have you ever had this message when trying to use content sync?
"The drush command 'content-sync:export' could not be found." I refreshed the cache and nothing changes

Comment: content sync relies on yml file ( no automation). Entity pilot charges money.