# How to create new entity within a hook?

Tags: entities, hooks

I am trying to create a hook that creates a new entity('Notification') when an entity of another type is created (either of type 'Deadline' or 'Message'), but I can't seem to figure out how to add a new entity from a hook, am I completely missing something?

My hook in ost.module looks like this:

```
function ost_hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create(EntityInterface $entity){
  if ($entity->getEntityType() == ('Deadline' || 'Message')){
    createNotification($entity);
  }
}
```

The function which is called looks like this:

```
function createNotification(EntityInterface $notification){
  $newentity = EntityInterface::create([
    'title' => $notification->label() . "notification",
    'field_content' => $notification->toLink()
  ]);
  $newentity->save();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically create nodes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185442/programmatically-create-nodes). Replace `node` with your own entity.

Comment: Don't save an entity in a create hook. The correct hook would be hook_entity_insert() in your case. Unless you want to create the second entity to reference it in the first one, but then reference it without saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code solved it for me:

```
function ost_notifications_entity_insert(EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->bundle() == 'deadline' || $entity->bundle() == 'message') {
    $new_entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->create([
      'type' => 'notification',
      'title' => $entity->label(),
      'field_content' => "content"
    ]);
    $new_entity->save();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That code needs to be changed for the following reasons.

In PHP, `$entity->getEntityType() == ('Deadline' || 'Message')` doesn't check that `$entity->getEntityType()` returns either `'Deadline'` or `'Message'`. Actually, the code you wrote is equivalent to the following one.

```php
if ($entity->getEntityType() == TRUE) {
  createNotification($entity);
}
```

`getEntityType()` doesn't return the ID of the type of the entity, but its definition. The method that returns the ID of the type of the entity is `getEntityTypeId()`.

It doesn't make sense to check the value returned from `$entity->getEntityTypeId()` in `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create()` because `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create()` is invoked only for the *ENTITY_TYPE* entities. (You are also supposed to implement `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create()` by replacing *ENTITY_TYPE* with the entity type, for example *node* for the Node entity, or *user* for the User entity.)

`EntityInterface` is an interface, not a class; as such, it's never used to call a method, even if it's statically called as in the code you are using.

The correct code is similar to the following one. I assume that *ost_hook* is the module machine name, *notification* is entity type, and `Notification` is the class implementing the entity you are trying to create.

```php
function ost_hook_entity_create(EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'Deadline' || $entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'Message') {
    $new_entity = Notification::create([
      'title' => $entity->label() . " notification",
      'field_content' => $entity->toLink()
    ]);
    $new_entity->save();
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the following code.

```php
function ost_hook_entity_create(EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'Deadline' || $entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'Message') {
    $new_entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('notification')->create([
      'title' => $entity->label() . " notification",
      'field_content' => $entity->toLink()
    ]);
    $new_entity->save();
  }
}
```

If the file containing the hook is *ost.module* (as I suspect), the function implementing the hook is `ost_entity_create()`, not `ost_hook_entity_create()`.

I used `hook_entity_create()` because the code needs to be executed for two different entity types. Using `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create()`, I should  implement two hooks. (I assume that *dealine* and *message* are the entity machine names, in the same way the machine name for the Node entity is *node*.)

```php
function ost_deadline_create(EntityInterface $entity) {
  $new_entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('notification')->create([
    'title' => $entity->label() . " notification",
    'field_content' => $entity->toLink()
  ]);
  $new_entity->save();
}

function ost_message_create(EntityInterface $entity) {
  $new_entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('notification')->create([
    'title' => $entity->label() . " notification",
    'field_content' => $entity->toLink()
  ]);
  $new_entity->save();
}
```

As side note, functions implemented from a module should always be prefixed by the module machine name. A module shouldn't have a `createNotification()` function, which should instead be called `ost_create_notification()` (assuming that *ost* is the module machine name).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am gonna try it out and see if it works.

Comment: I get the following error message when running the code your provided:

Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: The "Notification" entity type does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 846 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).

Comment: You need to verify what the entity type ID is. With the few information given in the question, I cannot tell you what that exactly is.