# How to programmatically reference entities?

Tags: entities, hooks

I am trying to reference an entity within my hook, so that every time a new entity is inserted, I create another entity referencing the first entity. I have not yet found a working way to reference an existing entity in my "field_content" when creating a new entity. 
My code looks like the below excerpt:

```
function ost_notifications_entity_insert(EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->bundle() == 'deadline' || $entity->bundle() == 'message') {
    $new_entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->create([
      'type' => 'notification',
      'title' => $entity->label(),
      'field_content' => "referenced entity goes here"
    ]);
    $new_entity->save();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by 4k4 in the comments, the most robust way is assign an entity object to the field like so:

```
$new_entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->create([
  'type' => 'notification',
  'title' => $entity->label(),
  'field_content' => [
    'entity' => $entity,
  ],
]);
```

For posterity, you can also do it by setting the field column (target_id) directly, but this is only useful if you have a saved entity. The first example will work for both new and existing entities.

```
$new_entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->create([
  'type' => 'notification',
  'title' => $entity->label(),
  'field_content' => [
    'target_id' => $entity->id(),
  ],
]);
```

Comment: Thank you @Clive, that worked!

Comment: When you have an entity object you can put the entity there as well `'entity' => $entity`. The advantage, this can be an unsaved entity which doesn't have an id yet and it gets saved together with the parent entity, for example when submitted in a form. This is connected to the previous question where the hook type was unclear https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/295226/how-to-create-new-entity-within-a-hook. This would then work for both hooks.

Comment: The entity example is more useful @4k4, thanks, I'll add that to the answer