# Is there a working example of programmatically creating a webform?

Tags: webforms, 9

Is there a working example of programmatically creating a webform?

I just need to see what works. The smallest excerpt will be helping out a lot. I can build on a foundation.

Comment: See [webform_example_custom_form](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/-/tree/8.x-5.x/modules/webform_example_custom_form) module.

Answer (score 3):

When you look around how to programmatically create a node you will finde patterns like [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/189095/15055):

> ```
> $node = Node::create([
>   'type'        => 'article',
>   'title'       => 'Druplicon test',
>   'field_image' => [
>     'target_id' => $file->id(),
>     'alt' => 'Hello world',
>     'title' => 'Goodbye world'
>   ],
> ]);
> $node->save();
> ```

Maybe that's similar for webforms or webform submissions? Okay, let's scan Webform's codebase for the following patterns: `Webform::create` and `WebformSubmission::create`. Wow! Lots of samples just in the module's code! Let's take these two as a start:

- [`WebformSubmission::create`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/-/blob/8.x-5.20-beta5/modules/webform_demo/webform_demo_group/webform_demo_group.install#L150-159)
- [`Webform::create`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/-/blob/8.x-5.20-beta5/tests/src/Functional/Settings/WebformSettingsFormTitleTest.php#L30-42)

Note that you also automatically can create webforms (not webform submissions, but webforms) by exporting config on one environment and importing it on different environments.