# Programmatically add a node

Tags: nodes, 9, external-scripts

Some years ago I made a Drupal 7 site. I want to remake the site with Drupal 9.

In Drupal 7 I added nodes programmatically with this PHP code.

```php
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$data = $_GET['d'];

AddNewNode($data);

function AddNewNode($data) {
  list($installlanguage, $playerid) = explode('|', $data);
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'new_install';
  node_object_prepare($node);
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
  $node->field_hm_new_installlanguage[$node->language][0]['value'] =   $installlanguage;
  $node->field_hm_new_install_playerid[$node->language][0]['value'] = $playerid;
  node_save($node);
}
```

The code doesn't work in Drupal 9.

I tried to search Google for *drupal 9 add content programmatically*, but I don't seem to get any useful result. Most links are about Drupal 8.

I also tried the following code, but I get this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Drupal\node\Entity\Node" not found

```php
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$data = $_GET['d'];
AddNewGameInstall($data);

function AddNewGameInstall($data) {
  $node = Node::create([
    'type' => 'new_game_install',
    'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
    'field_device_language' => $devicelanguage,
    'field_player_id' => $playerid
  ]);
  $node->save();
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically create nodes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185442/programmatically-create-nodes)

Comment: There's not much of a difference between D8 and D9. Most of the D8 answers get constantly updated to replace deprecated code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31823730/2199525

Comment: @leymannx Thank you for your help. I edited the code, but I'm getting an error. I guess I'm missing some initialization code.

Comment: On what file are you adding this code?

Comment: @No Sssweat in xampp/htdocs/sitename/newgameinstall.php

Comment: What is that file for? Why is it in the root? You aren't loading the autoloader.

Comment: @Kevin The file is to add a new node from an external app by sending an HTTP request. It has always been in the root for Drupal 7. How can I load the autoloader? Thank you.

Comment: This does not seem secure.

Comment: @Kevin If it's not secure to put the PHP file in the root, then what folder should I use?